# Creating a brick wall with Python turtle graphics

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I have an idea on how to make the wall, but I have to implement spaces between the bricks and it has to fill up the window. Would anyone have any suggestions on how best to implement this? My code is this:

```
import turtle
x1= -300
y1= 270

turtle.setup(600, 600)
turtle.speed(0)
turtle.bgcolor('black')
for y in range (1, 16):

    for x in range(10):
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.goto(x1, y1)
        turtle.pencolor('red')
        turtle.pendown()
        turtle.fillcolor('red')
        turtle.begin_fill()
        turtle.forward(50)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(25)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(50)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(25)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.end_fill()
        x1 += 60
    if y % 2 == 0:
        x1 -= -200

    else:
        x1 = -300
        y1 -= 270
```

After the first row, the y is supposed to increment itself and make another row below the first one until it fills up the screen.

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far

Comment: Please explain in detail the idea you mention and show the code you wrote when trying to implement it. Please elaborate what you mean by "fill up the window", maybe be showing how what you did does not fill up the window. A suggestion how to implement this is: Start with a program which kind of does almost what you want (you already have such a program, don't you?). Then change something and observe the effect. Maybe you achieve an effect which you can use to get closer; otherwise undo the change. Repeat.

Comment: Sorry about that, I was still in the process of trial and error when I asked this so what I had was a rough starting point that I quite was't ready to show outright. apologies for that

Answer (score 0):

Even if this isn't what you had in mind, it should give you some ideas on how to proceed.  It's based on *stamping* instead of *drawing* and sets the coordinate system to be brick-centric:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

CURSOR_SIZE = 20

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(600, 600)  # 12 x 24 bricks
screen.setworldcoordinates(0, 0, 12, 24)  # coordinates based on bricks
screen.bgcolor('black')

turtle = Turtle('square', visible=False)
turtle.penup()
turtle.speed('fastest')
turtle.color('black', 'red')
turtle.shapesize(25 / CURSOR_SIZE, 50 / CURSOR_SIZE, 5)  # turn cursor into brick

for y in range(24):
    turtle.setposition(-0.5 * (y % 2), y + 0.3)

    for x in range(13):  # baker's dozen due to brick skew
        turtle.stamp()
        turtle.forward(1)

screen.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: I like this idea, the issue is, my teacher is very nitpicky about how we do our code in class. While we do sometimes find other ways to do things, if it isn't close to what she wanted or asked for then we have to clean it up and fix it and it's rather annoying. What I posted is pretty close to what she wanted me to do, my issue is the if else statement math is either done wrong or my numbers are wrong and i'm not sure which one it is and it's driving my bonkers

Comment: We haven't done anything with stamping either, as out teacher wants us to draw it out in python with turtle to learn how to better do it and such